# How to run docker in Ciricle CI orbs?

Tags: spring, maven, circleci, circleci-2.0

CircleCI introduces orb in 2.1, I am trying to add Circle Ci config my [sample project](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-jwt-sample).

But in my testing codes, I have used test containers to simplify the dependent config of my integration tests.

When committing my codes, the Circle CI running is failed.

```sh
org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Container startup failed
Caused by: org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerFetchException: Can't get Docker image: RemoteDockerImage(imageName=mongo:4.0.10, imagePullPolicy=DefaultPullPolicy())
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please see logs and check configuration
```

My Circle CI config.

```yaml
version: 2.1

orbs:
  maven: circleci/maven@1.0.1
  codecov: codecov/codecov@1.1.0

jobs:
  codecov:
    machine:
      image: ubuntu-1604:201903-01
    steps:
       - codecov/upload

workflows:
  build:
    jobs:
      - maven/test:
          command: "-q verify -Pcoverage"
      - codecov:
          requires:
            - maven/test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it run myself.

The `maven` orb provides reusable `jobs` and `commands`, but by default, it used a JDK `executor`, does not provide a Docker runtime.

My solution is giving up the reusable job, and reuse some commands from the `maven` orb in your own jobs.

```yaml
version: 2.1

orbs:
  maven: circleci/maven@1.0.1
  codecov: codecov/codecov@1.1.0
executors:
  docker-mongo:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/openjdk:14-jdk-buster
      - image: circleci/mongo:latest
jobs:
  build:
    executor: docker-mongo
    steps:
      - checkout
      - maven/with_cache:
          steps:
            - run: mvn -q test verify -Pcoverage
      - maven/process_test_results
      - codecov/upload:
          when: on_success
workflows:
  build:
    jobs:
      - build
```